# Won't fade in when using .show("slow")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs that are set to show only one at a time, but I cannot seem to get them to slowly fade in with .show("slow").  Fading out works fine with .hide("slow").  Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#162').hide();
  $('#164').hide();

  function reveal162() {
  $('#162').show("slow");
  $('#164').hide("slow");
  }
  $('#162link').click(reveal162);

  function reveal164() {
  $('#164').show("slow");
  $('#162').hide("slow");
  }
  $('#164link').click(reveal164);
});
```

jsFiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/swiftsly/9Yx8b/

Comment: You can put time in millisecond in .show()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To animate using show(), element need to be displayed as block, you can use `display:block`

```
version{
    display:block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Yx8b/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle example is using non-standard tags such as `<vn>` and `<version>`. The show and hide methods work as expected when these tags are replaced with `<div>`. Is there a reason for the non-standard tags?

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, I can just use <div> and it works fine.

Comment: If you want to use your custom tags A. Wolff's answer will work as it gives your custom tags the display block property they need to work with the show animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions instead.

Comment: When I tried that in the OP's fiddle it didn't make any difference: the fade _in_ didn't work, the element just appeared instantly. (But even if it had worked, a fade is a different type of animation to what you get with `.show("slow")`.)

Comment: You're right, and as @A. Wolf said, to be able to apply the effect, element need to be block('d). 
The OP wanted to apply a fadeIn/Out effect, so why not using the fadeX functions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#162').fadeOut();
  $('#164').fadeOut();

  function reveal162() {
  $('#162').fadeIn("slow");
  $('#164').fadeOut("slow");
  }
  $('#162link').click(reveal162);

  function reveal164() {
  $('#164').fadeIn("slow");
  $('#162').fadeOut("slow");
  }
  $('#164link').click(reveal164);
});
```